# How to change a style property of element by class name without any use of ID's in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a school project and it's my first time using JS, and we are not allowed to use any ID's for css styling, but on some event that the user does I want to change the style of a `div` in the page:

HTML:

```
<div class="ads">
  ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ads{
    display:block;
    //and some other style properties
}
```

and when the user do the event I want to change the display property into :

```
display : none;
```

I know how it can be done using ID for the element, but how can it be done only by a class name?

I would like to be able to do it something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ads').style.display=none;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that there is only one element with that class, use the first element of the `NodeList` that [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ads')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Nice downvoting spree.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ads')[0].style.display ='none';
```

Comment: Or loop over the returned list if you want to change all of them.

Answer (score 2):

If you have just a one element with class`"ads"`, you can use:

```
document.querySelector('.ads').style.display='none'
```

Else, if you have more than one element you can add a unique class name for you element like this

```
<div class="ads foo">
```

and using `document.querySelector('.foo').style.display='none'`
for changing it's style.

Comment: Note that `none` needs to be wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should put index, also the string after the equal sign must be with quotation marks, like below:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ads')[0].style.display="none";
```

[w3schools](http://w3schools)

> The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.